# Adding a space into every row in a column, with space position dependent on character length

Tags: r

I want to be add a white space into every row of one column in a data frame. This column is character in terms of data type. The position of this white space is dependent on the length of the string in each row.

e.g for all rows in this particular column, all rows with less than 6 characters should have the white space after the second character, whilst those with 7 or more characters should have the white space after the 4th character

As an example, looking at the Iris dataset and the Species column, for the setosa rows I would want a white space after the second character, so "setosa" becomes "se tosa"

I know that this will be an ifelse statement, but I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Did the solutions I posted help? If so please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first determine the number of characters in `iris$Species`:

```
iris$Species_char <- nchar(as.character(iris$Species))
```

Based on this new column you can define an `ifelse` statement, with `iris$Species_char <= 6` as your condition, the insertion of whitespace after the *second* character as action to be taken if condition evaluates to TRUE, and insertion of whitespace after the fourth character as action to be taken if condition evaluates to FALSE. To make sure the characters before and after the insertion point are recollected we use backreference, with `\\1` referring back to the chars before, and `\\2` referring back to the chars after the insertion point:

```
iris$Species <- ifelse(iris$Species_char <= 6, 
                       sub("(\\w{2})(.*)", "\\1 \\2", iris$Species), 
                       sub("(\\w{4})(.*)", "\\1 \\2", iris$Species))
```

The above two steps in one step:

```
iris$Species <- ifelse(nchar(iris$Species) <= 6, 
                       sub("(\\w{2})(.*)", "\\1 \\2", iris$Species), 
                       sub("(\\w{4})(.*)", "\\1 \\2", iris$Species))
```

**EDIT**: Using `dplyr` and `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
iris %>%
  mutate(Species = if_else(str_count(Species) <= 6, sub("(\\w{2})(.*)", "\\1 \\2", Species), sub("(\\w{4})(.*)", "\\1 \\2", Species)))
```

Result:

```
iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width     Species Species_char
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     se tosa            6
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     se tosa            6
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     se tosa            6
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     se tosa            6
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     se tosa            6
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     se tosa            6
11           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     se tosa            6
12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     se tosa            6
13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     se tosa            6
14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     se tosa            6
15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     se tosa            6
16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     se tosa            6
17           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     se tosa            6
18           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     se tosa            6
19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     se tosa            6
20           5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3     se tosa            6
21           5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     se tosa            6
22           5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     se tosa            6
23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     se tosa            6
24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     se tosa            6
25           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     se tosa            6
26           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     se tosa            6
27           5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4     se tosa            6
28           5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     se tosa            6
29           5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     se tosa            6
31           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     se tosa            6
32           5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4     se tosa            6
33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     se tosa            6
34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
35           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     se tosa            6
36           5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     se tosa            6
37           5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     se tosa            6
38           4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     se tosa            6
39           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     se tosa            6
40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     se tosa            6
41           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     se tosa            6
42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     se tosa            6
43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     se tosa            6
44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     se tosa            6
45           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     se tosa            6
46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     se tosa            6
47           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     se tosa            6
48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     se tosa            6
50           5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     se tosa            6
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 vers icolor           10
52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 vers icolor           10
53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 vers icolor           10
54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 vers icolor           10
55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 vers icolor           10
56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 vers icolor           10
57           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 vers icolor           10
58           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 vers icolor           10
59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 vers icolor           10
60           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 vers icolor           10
61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 vers icolor           10
62           5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 vers icolor           10
63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 vers icolor           10
64           6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 vers icolor           10
65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 vers icolor           10
66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 vers icolor           10
67           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 vers icolor           10
68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 vers icolor           10
69           6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 vers icolor           10
70           5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 vers icolor           10
71           5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 vers icolor           10
72           6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 vers icolor           10
73           6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 vers icolor           10
74           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 vers icolor           10
75           6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 vers icolor           10
76           6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 vers icolor           10
77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 vers icolor           10
78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 vers icolor           10
79           6.0         2.9          4.5         1.5 vers icolor           10
80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 vers icolor           10
81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 vers icolor           10
82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 vers icolor           10
83           5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 vers icolor           10
84           6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6 vers icolor           10
85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 vers icolor           10
86           6.0         3.4          4.5         1.6 vers icolor           10
87           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 vers icolor           10
88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 vers icolor           10
89           5.6         3.0          4.1         1.3 vers icolor           10
90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 vers icolor           10
91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 vers icolor           10
92           6.1         3.0          4.6         1.4 vers icolor           10
93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 vers icolor           10
94           5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 vers icolor           10
95           5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 vers icolor           10
96           5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 vers icolor           10
97           5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 vers icolor           10
98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 vers icolor           10
99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 vers icolor           10
100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 vers icolor           10
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virg inica            9
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virg inica            9
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virg inica            9
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virg inica            9
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virg inica            9
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virg inica            9
107          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virg inica            9
108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virg inica            9
109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8  virg inica            9
110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virg inica            9
111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virg inica            9
112          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9  virg inica            9
113          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virg inica            9
114          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virg inica            9
115          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virg inica            9
116          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3  virg inica            9
117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virg inica            9
118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virg inica            9
119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virg inica            9
120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virg inica            9
121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3  virg inica            9
122          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virg inica            9
123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virg inica            9
124          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8  virg inica            9
125          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virg inica            9
126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virg inica            9
127          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8  virg inica            9
128          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8  virg inica            9
129          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1  virg inica            9
130          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6  virg inica            9
131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virg inica            9
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virg inica            9
133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2  virg inica            9
134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virg inica            9
135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virg inica            9
136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virg inica            9
137          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4  virg inica            9
138          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8  virg inica            9
139          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8  virg inica            9
140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virg inica            9
141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virg inica            9
142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virg inica            9
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virg inica            9
144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virg inica            9
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virg inica            9
146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virg inica            9
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virg inica            9
148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virg inica            9
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virg inica            9
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virg inica            9
```